# Detect if keyboard is open from Service

Tags: android, service, keyboard, detect

I know it's kind of tricky to even detect or know when the soft keyboard is open in an activity. I'm just wondering if there is a way to detect whether or not the keyboard is open from a service. I want to build a feature into my service that disables itself when the keyboard is open; regardless where the user is on the device. Thanks!